# Authentication to SharePoint Online REST API from ASP.NET Core

Tags: rest, asp.net-core, sharepoint

I have an existing PHP tool which I'm rewriting in .NET Core 3.0 which browses data on SharePoint Online, Exchange Online and OneDrive.

It has an app registration which I've approve for accessing various tenants, then the tool use oAuth calls using app flow to get the access token to use in calls to read data etc.

The issue I'm having is generating an access token in .NET Core to access SharePoint online using REST. The technique of using ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder with my client id, secret etc then calling AcquireTokenForClient seems to work for Exchange Online EWS and Graph but fails for SharePoint Online, the response containing "Unsupported app only token."

My PHP code doing the equivalent also includes a JWT as 'client_assertion' and I've found the following article which has code that appears to do very similar steps to what my PHP code does: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-client-assertions (I appreciate the code is written about authentication to Azure but the construction of the claim looks so similar to the PHP construction of the JWT code. And that code I think assumes we have a certificate in a private store with a private key)

I've tried to do the equivalent using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt (not all the classes in that article are available in core) and after working around several challenges ended up being able to create a JWT token, but when used to generate an access token and make a call on the tenant, it returns a 401 access denied. It could be one of a dozen places in the code I'm using to put the token together since I don't have a solid example of exactly what I'm trying to do.

My interest is specifically in using REST with SharePoint, since it supports some operations Graph v1 doesn't support and I don't want to use Graph beta, and I'm aware there are some ports of CSOM to run on Core but prefer not to go that route.

So what I'd like to find is an example addressing the following constraints:

- Runs in C# as a "netcoreapp3.0" app
- Connects to SharePoint Online using the REST API
- For the certificate required to sign the JWT I have a CERTIFICATE file, PRIVATE KEY file and thumb file
- I'm trying to run operations such as 'list root site details' which are allowed by the app registration
- I already have the tenant URL, id, app registration client id and client secret